# django-cms 404 errors when not logged in

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

I'm running django-cms 2.4.1 and I'm getting 404 not found errors when attempting to access any page (other than the root) when not logged in.  Once I log in to the admin console, all pages are accessible as expected.  There are no page permissions set and I've double-checked that "login required" is not set anywhere.  Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: Did you publish the pages?
More from the docs http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html#publishing-a-page

Comment: Are you by any chance using multilingual options?  If so, the following _may_ help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17699940/378136