# Django CMS pages throwing 404 for users who are not logged in to the admin

Tags: django, django-cms

All the pages throw a 404 error on a site for users who are not logged in. But if I log in to the admin and go back to view the site, all the pages are fine and viewable.

I've been using Django CMS for years and haven't come across this before. The only difference with this site is the default language is french, in my settings I have:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('fr', 'Francais'),
]
```

as my LANGUAGES setting and here is my `LANGUAGE_CODE`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
```

Here are my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

and my middleware...

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
)
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a plus sign :)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
```

Comment: OMG... Maybe I should leave this task for another day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation to you: I'm using multiple languages with Django-CMS.

My issue was related to the `CMS_LANGUAGES` variable I'd defined: I'd simply lifted a portion of the [example from the docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-languages).

[A comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1881#issuecomment-19138047) helped point me in the correct direction.

I'd previously had the variable set up as:

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ...
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en', 'de', 'fr'],
        'redirect_on_fallback': False,
        'public': False,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

Notice the definition of the `public` boolean.

Also, make sure that you follow the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-languages) with respect to setting up your language variables within the `CMS_LANGUAGES` dictionary.

Replacing the above with  `'public': True` got things working for me again.